How to describe the elements in $A\otimes K$ with infinite matrix $\left(a_{ij}\right)$?
Let $A$ be $C^*$-algebra and $K$ be the $C^*$-algebra of all compact operators in a separable Hilbert space. As we all know if infinite matrix $\left(a_{ij}\right)$ satisfies the following inequality
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i}\left(\sum_{j}\Vert a_{ij}\Vert^2\right)^{1/2}<\infty\  \text{and} \ \sum_{j}\left(\sum_{i}\Vert a_{ij}\Vert^2\right)^{1/2}<\infty,
\end{equation*}
then $\left(a_{ij}\right)$ could be viewed as an element in $A\otimes K$.
I would like to know whether this condition is a necessary condition or not?
Furthermore, what is the sufficient and necessary condition for that infinite matrix $\left(a_{ij}\right)$ could be viewed as an element $A\otimes K$?
More generally, Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\tilde{H}$ be the direct sum of countable copies of $H$. What is the sufficient and necessary condition for that infinite matrix $\left(a_{ij}\right)$  could be viewed as an element in $B\left(\tilde{H}\right)$ or $K\left(\tilde{H}\right)$?

Every compact operator could be approximated by finite rank operators, and hence we have the same estimation:given $\varepsilon$>0
, we could find an integer $>0$
such that $\sum_{i>N} \Vert a_{ij}\Vert^2<\varepsilon$
for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$ and  $\sum_{j>N} \Vert a_{ij}\Vert^2<\varepsilon$
for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$
